# Appending to Nested Dictionary in R

Tags: r, dictionary

I'm facing the issue that I cannot seem to get a dictionary created of the correct form. I want to append to a nested list element of the first so that for example I can have:

```
mylist[[index]] <- list("TSI" <- list(), "type"=mytype)
```

I'd then like to add elements to the dictionary TSI so that I have:

```
mylist[[index]][["TSI"]] <- list(mylist[[index]][["TSI"]], key=value)
```

but when I keep doing this i.e.

```
mylist[[index]][["TSI"]] <- list(mylist[[index]][["TSI"]], '2'=200)
mylist[[index]][["TSI"]] <- list(mylist[[index]][["TSI"]], '3'=300)
```

I find that when I do this, I don't get a list and the dictionary/list I'm trying to build is only containing one value.

As is suggested in the answer I have tried the following which is in a loop:

```
  # type is some kind of string i.e. "3"
  # myTSI is a value i.e. 400
  # index is a value i.e. 1
  mylist[[index]][["TSI"]] <- c(mylist[[index]][["TSI"]], type=myTSI)
```

index does not change for this case, but type does, so ideally should build up a series of entries in  `mylist[[index]][["TSI"]]` where `mylist[[index]][["TSI"]][["6"]]` gives the myTSI for that type. However upon exiting the loop, I just get when typing:

```
mylist[[index]][["TSI"]]
```

I get the following

```
type
"648746"
```

but no dictionary list. Which is odd, because if I do the following in the loop:

```
 mylist[[index]][["TSI"]] <- c(mylist[[index]][["TSI"]], "3"=100)
 mylist[[index]][["TSI"]] <- c(mylist[[index]][["TSI"]], "4"=400)
```

when printing `mylist[[index]][["TSI"]]`

I get

```
3   4 
100 400
```

Can't work out why this is the case.

Comment: The problem is the `"TSI" <- list()` in your first command. That does not create a list entry named "TSI", instead it binds an empty list to the symbol "TSI", and that empty list then becomes the first (unnamed!) entry in `mylist[[index]]`. Then later when you try to access `mylist[[index]][["TSI"]]` that entry in the list does not exist, so that returns a `NULL` object to which you then append a list entry named `'2'` with value 200. If you do `mylist[[index]] <- list("TSI" = list(), "type"="mytype")` in the first line, your code will work as intended.

Comment: @Navonod Please don't ask the same question twice - you can edit your question if you need to.  Since this question now has an answer, I've voted to close the previous version. http://stackoverflow.com/q/22193805/134830

Comment: @RichieCotton, I should have tried to delete the other first. Agreed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a construct like this, where `l` is of type list:

```
l = c(l, list(key=value))
```

This will concatinate two lists together.

R implements a copy-on-write paradigm, therefore, incrementally appending elements to a list will be extremely inefficient. Even my above suggestion is inefficient as it suffers from the same issue. The best approach is along the following lines:

```
tsi = lapply(some_data, some_function_to_populate_list)
mylist[[index]]$TSI = tsi
```

In this way you avoid copying `mylist` and your nested list every time you ad an element

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying but seemingly I'm having trouble with this and I simply don't know the dictionary/list is not appending. I have written more above, in the above Question for more comment. It seems to be ok, when I hard-type values in, I get the appending, but when going through the loop, with variables for key:value it does not work.

Comment: @Navonod imagine you have `l = list(a=1, b=2)`, then I expect the following result from `l=list(l, c=3)`: `[[a=1, b=2], c=3]`, i.e. a nested list with the first element unnamed. What you seem to want is `[a=1, b=2, c=3]`, which is a concatination and is achieved by using `c` with two lists, so putting value `c=3` into a new list you should have: `l=c(l, list(c=3))` resulting in `[a=1, b=2, c=3]`. This is what my above answer is about. Alternatively, if only add one value at a time you can just set it directly into your list: `name="c"; l[[name]] = 3`. Both methods are suboptimal though.

Comment: Thanks but the `[[index]][[type]][[name]]=3` approach does not work, strangely there is only ever the last name pushed into the dictionary/list, despite going round the loop N times and getting N different 'names' and values. So if I print `[[index]][[type]]` I don't get the key value pairs.